# concat subsections of a video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to take several subsections of a video and concatenate them using the [concat ffmpeg filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat). It's just like the [the example in the FFmpeg documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Examples-12), except that all of the clips are from the same source video.

Here is what I am trying:

```
ffmpeg \
  -ss 1.0 -frames:v 20 -i myInput.mp4 \
  -ss 2.0 -frames:v 20 -i myInput.mp4 \
  -ss 3.0 -frames:v 20 -i myInput.mp4 \
  -filter_complex '[0:0][0:1][1:0][1:1][2:0][2:1]concat=n=3:v=1:a=2[v][a1][a2]' \
  -map '[v]' -map '[a1]' -map '[a2]' myOutput.mp4
```

When I try this, I get the following error ([full output here](http://pastebin.com/z22U888G)):

```
Stream specifier ':0' in filtergraph description [0:0][0:1][1:0][1:1][2:0][2:1]concat=n=3:v=1:a=2[v][a1][a2] matches no streams.
```

A few things:

- What's with the error? According to the stderr output, those streams do exist. What am I missing?
- Shouldn't the -ss (and -frames:v) be reflected in the "Duration: ... start: ... " line of the stderr output when the inputs are listed?
- Will the "-frames:v" option even work to specify the duration of an input? (apparently -t is only for output??) Is there a way to specify the duration of an input with seconds instead of frames?

Help me LordNeckbeard -- you're my only hope!

Answer (score 1):

```
ffmpeg.exe -f concat -safe 0 -i "D:\Clips\concatepath.txt" -c copy "D:\Clips\ConcatinatedVideo.mp4"
```

Where concatepath.txt file is containing all videos path.
Here is an example

```
file 'D:\Clips\video1.mp4'
file 'D:\Clips\video2.mp4'
```